# How to stop a Journey Builder email send in a specific date forward using Exclusion Script?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, exclusion-script

I have an email which needs to be stopped from being sent on a particular date moving forward (20170816) in a journey. For this purpose I have tried using the Exclusion Script. However the script stops the email send but it should allow the email to be sent before that date. And unfortunately I don't receive the email even though I will reverse the logic.

Here is the script:

```
IF FormatDate(SystemDateToLocalDate(Now()), "YYYYMMDD") >= '20170816' THEN

    Not Empty(Lookup('Sendable_DE','EMAIL','EMAIL',emailaddr))

ENDIF
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Exclusion Script needs to evaluate to true, so you can simply put the following string in the Exclusion Script text area field:

```js
FormatDate(SystemDateToLocalDate(Now()), "YYYYMMDD") >= '20170816'
```

I've tested this and if works. If specified date matches the current date or any date after this specified date (which I understand is what you are trying to achieve), then the email will not be sent.

Comment: ok that is strange. Anyways does it work if i reverse the logic which is if the AMPScript (Exclusion Script) is not true?

Comment: If the script evaluates to false, then the email will be sent.

Comment: Just have another question is there a way we can stop sending journey builder emails on weekends?

Comment: @pragyanshukukreti do you want to *skip* sending or *delay* sending emails on weekends (e.g. don't send until Monday)?

Comment: I think I want to delay sending emails on weekends. Eg if any contact is being pushed on saturday, email should reach out to their inbox on Monday.

Comment: You can't do this out of the box in Journey Builder. I've done something similar using a Custom Activity to send a Triggered Send Email immediately or at a specific time. You could also use the `{{Contact.Key}}` string in an Update Data Activity to write the Subscriber Key to a DE and configure an automation to send to records to the DE each weekday (then remove the records from the DE after sending using AMPscript DeleteDE function).